# How to pass a value from view (that does not redirect) to another view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, view, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have a several indexes that share the same edit view, in order to let the Edit post method decide which index view should redirect the user to after the submission, i will pass the name of the page to the Edit view and then i will save it in a variable, which will be used in an if statement later.

So i have this edit button, the value saved in the page in the current page name.

```
<td>
    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" 
      name="Page" 
      value="@System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ViewContext.View.Path)" 
      class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
</td>
```

the editUserViewModel

```cs
public class EditUserViewModel
{ 
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Page { get; set; } //additional property
}
```

Edit get example

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {id} cannor be found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel
    {
        Name = user.Name,
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Edit post

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {model.Id} cannot be found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    else
    {
        user.Name = model.Name;

        var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        if (model.Page == "Index1")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index1", "User");
        } else if (model.Page == "Index2")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index2", "User");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

finally the Edit View

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
    <h4>Edit</h4>
    <hr />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Page" /> //i want to save the previous page name in this property
    @*<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>*@
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id"></label>
        <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="user.name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>  @*wrong place*@
    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Back to List</a> //default redirect
</form>
```

So, how can i redirect the page name from the index to the edit view and save it with the other information?

I would like to thank David Liang and mj1313 for the answers, both worked so well for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it like your login screen, with something like `returnUrl` that you can use to redirect back after the form post?

You can build a little extension method to get the current URL, with query string:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace DL.SO.ViewToView.WebUI.Extensions
{
    public static class HttpRequestExtension
    {
        public static string GetCurrentAbsoluteUrl(this HttpRequest request)
        {
            return $"{ request.Scheme }://{ request.Host }{ GetCurrentRelativeUrl(request) }";
        }

        public static string GetCurrentRelativeUrl(this HttpRequest request)
        {
            return $"{ request.Path }{ request.QueryString }";
        }
    }
}
```

**-- Update --**

Here I gave out 2 extension methods to get either the absolute Url, with scheme and host, and the relative url.

Previously OP's author mentioned that a Url like "https://localhost:44376/User/Index" is not considered as local url by `IUrlHelper.IsLocalUrl()`. And I looked up [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.islocalurl?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and confirmed that is indeed the case. So within the app, it will use `GetCurrentRelativeUrl()` instead.

**----**

Then your edit button link will become

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="user" asp-action="edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"
   asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.GetCurrentRelativeUrl()" class="btn btn-primary">
    Edit
</a>
```

You can place this button basically on any page, as long as you supply `@item.Id`.

Remember to include the namespace of the extension method in the `_ViewImports.cshtml`.

[image]

See the screenshot? It captures the current URL correctly, with or without query strings!

This `returnUrl` will be passed in as one of the query string parameters, just like the `id`:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, string returnUrl)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {id} cannot be found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }

    var vm = new EditUserViewModel
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = user.Name,
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Of course, your view model will need to be changed to:

```cs
public class EditUserViewModel
{ 
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And your form just needs to save it as hidden input, just like how you would do with the `Id`:

```
<form method="post" asp-area="" asp-controller="user" asp-action="edit">
    <h4>Edit</h4>
    <hr />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" />

    ...
</form>
```

Finally, on the form post, after you're done with the logic, you just need to redirect to `returnUrl`, **as long as** it's a valid local URL:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditUserViewModel vm)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(vm.Id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {vm.Id} cannot be found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }
       
    user.Name = vm.Name;

    var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(vm.ReturnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(vm.ReturnUrl);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This is a better idea of what i wanted, more flexible and with less code in the actions, thank you so much for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: So, this `Url.IsLocalUrl(vm.ReturnUrl)` gives me false, and I tried to return the same thing in the `else` clause but nothing occurs, any suggestion?

Comment: Show me `vm.ReturnUrl` you got.

Comment: @roo: opps sorry that was my bad. Apparently `https://localhost` is not considered as a local URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.islocalurl?view=aspnetcore-3.1. Let me fix the `GetCurrentUrl` extension.

Comment: @roo: Please see my update. I changed `HttpRequestExteions` now to include both `GetCurrentAbsoluteUrl()` and `GetCurrentRelativeUrl()`. Apparently `IsLocalUrl()` will return false if the url starts with the schema and host. So in your application, please use the `GetCurrentRelativeUrl()` instead. `GetCurrentAbsoluteUrl()` is just there to make things complete. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Its very kind of you.. Everything works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `asp-route-page` attribute to your `a` link:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" 
  asp-route-page="@System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ViewContext.View.Path)" 
  class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

Then change Edit get method, add a receive parameter `page`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, string page)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {id} cannor be found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }
    EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel
    {
        Name = user.Name,
        Page = page
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! i didn't expect to be this simple. I'm still not familiar with tag helpers so thank you for the new info.

Comment: Hi @roo, if my reply can help you solve the problem, you can mark it as answer, this will help others with similar problems to find a solution more easier, thanks :)

Comment: @roo If you don't pass the id, the user will be null and it will rerutn "NotFound"

Comment: ok! because in some cases my get function does not have an argument for the id, and I wondered why this doesn't work. Thank you anyways!